# Getting error when trying to save data to database in console app

Tags: c#

My app scans a folder for any changes made in it.  Once it has detected a file being added it should the save that file or path in my database.

But at the moment this is the error I am getting:

```
File created: New Text Document - Copy (2).txt
Unhandled exception. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the 
keyword 'File'.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, 
Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean 
breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean 
callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, 
SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, 
Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, 
String resetOptionsString)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior 
runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, 
SqlDataReader ds)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior 
runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, 
Boolean asyncWrite, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, 
Boolean 
sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at FileWatcher.Program.FileSystemWatcher_Created(Object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e) in 
C:\Users\Dev\source\repos\FileWatcher\FileWatcher\Program.cs:line 44
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFileSystemEventArgs(WatcherChangeTypes changeType, 
ReadOnlySpan`1 
name)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.ParseEventBufferAndNotifyForEach(Byte[] buffer)
at System.IO.FileSystemWatcher.ReadDirectoryChangesCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, 
NativeOverlapped* overlappedPointer)
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolBoundHandleOverlapped.CompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 
numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 
numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pNativeOverlapped)
ClientConnectionId:5ec97695-2345-4ecd-89b0-f77d4dc409ee
Error Number:156,State:1,Class:15
```

So this is the code I am using:

```
private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
        fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;
        fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += FileSystemWatcher_Deleted;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=Development-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial 
        Catalog=FileDB;Integrated Security=True";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(e.Name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();

        SqlCommand command;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable (File, Date) VALUES (@File, @Date)", 
 connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.Binary, file.Length).Value = file;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, file.Length).Value.ToString();
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I am not entirely sure what I am doing wrong with SQL command?

Please help

Thanks!

**EDIT**

It does read the directory and display the files in the console, but when it tries to save the data in the database the app then crashes with the above error code

**EDIT**

**FULL CODE AFTER EDIT**

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = "C:\\Database";
        MonitorDirectory(path);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void MonitorDirectory(string path)
    {
        FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        fileSystemWatcher.Path = path;
        fileSystemWatcher.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created;
        fileSystemWatcher.Renamed += FileSystemWatcher_Renamed;
        fileSystemWatcher.Deleted += FileSystemWatcher_Deleted;
        fileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcher_Created(object sender, 
    FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("File created: {0}", e.Name);

        string connectionString = @"Data Source=Development- 
        PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FileDB;Integrated Security=True";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(e.Name, FileMode.Open, 
        FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);
        byte[] file = reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);
        reader.Close();
        stream.Close();

        SqlCommand command;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable ([File], [Date]) 
        VALUES (@File, @Date)", connection);
        command.Parameters.Add("@File", SqlDbType.Binary, file.Length).Value = 
   file;
        command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 
   file.Length).Value.ToString();
        connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcher_Renamed(object sender, 
    FileSystemEventArgs e)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("File renamed: {0}", e.Name);
    }

    private static void FileSystemWatcher_Deleted(object sender, 
    FileSystemEventArgs e)

    {
        Console.WriteLine("File deleted: {0}", e.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing something for the parameter Date? Where is the value for it?

Comment: I cant see where you are **assigning** a value for the Data parameter either

Comment: I realize that now.  I just need it to save the date and timestamp as well

Comment: `command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, 
   file.Length).Value.ToString();`  This line makes no sense.

Comment: I got it working now (sort of)  it save now but it doesn't save the file just ... in databse

Answer (score 3):

In SQL, you need to escape user defined tokens that overlap keywords with square brackets, try replacing this line:

```cs
command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable (File, Date) VALUES (@File, @Date)", 
 connection);
```

with this:

```cs
command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable ([File], [Date]) VALUES (@File, @Date)", 
 connection);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but am still getting the same error :-(

Comment: You're getting the **exact** same error and it's pointing to the line I've quoted in my answer?

Comment: Hi My mistake had a typo.  The error I am getting is when it tries to save the datetime in my database `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at line `            command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, file.Length).Value.ToString();`

Comment: Gues I am not saving the date and time stamp correctly?

Comment: @KeithKing Commented about it 17 minutes ago. You are not setting any value for the Date parameter

Comment: @Steve Thank you I was just going to comment this. You're immediately calling `ToString()` on a `null` value

Answer (score 0):

File is a `TSQL` reserved `key word` and that's why you are getting an exception.

You need to change your query to the following to get it work:

```
command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO FileTable ([File], [Date]) VALUES (@File, @Date)", 
 connection);
```

Putting `[]` arround fields with the same names as `TSQL` keywords solves such issues

It would be also nice if you create your table as:

```
create table FileTable 
(
 [File] varbinary(MAX) null,
 [Date] nvarchar(50) null
)
```

And also change

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, file.Length).Value.ToString();
```

to:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime, file.Length).Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but am still getting the same error :-(

Comment: @KeithKing Check my edited answer. may be you need to recreate your table as I posted. This will absolutely work.

Comment: Deleted the table and re-created as suggested, but still not working - same error.  Maybe its not actually saving the file in the database.  I have updated my question with the full code.

Comment: @KeithKing Check my new answer

Answer (score 0):

Just an advice, use using keyword when initializing an object of Sql connection and command, this tells GC to process it after the clause.
Usage:
Using(sqlconnection sql = new sqlconnection(connstring)) {}
Any IDisposable class has this option